# What is the behavior of @CookieValue in SpringMVC when request contains multiple cookie with same name?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cookies

When handling REST request with a cookie, I use `@CookieValue` to retrieve the value of the cookie, likes:

```java
@GetMapping("/path")
public ResponseEntity doRequest(@CookieValue(value = "cookie_name", required = false) final String cookieValue) {
```

The question is, we could send multiple cookies with the same name to this endpoint, like:

```sh
curl -v http://localhost/path --cookie "cookie_name=abc; cookie_name=def"
```

What value will `cookieValue` get?

Tried with Spring boot 2.0.3, the value seems to be the `abc`, the first value. But could not find doc noted this behavior, so not sure if this coincidence or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It IS the first cookie with the required name would be used for retrieving the value.

*In Spring boot 2.0.3(spring-webmvc 5.0.7.RELEASE):*

From `ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver#resolveName`, it invokes `WebUtils#getCookie` to retrieve cookie for the given name.

Meanwhile, the Javadoc of `WebUtils#getCookie` noted:

> Retrieve the first cookie with the given name. Note that multiple cookies can have the same name but different paths or domains.